# Get value of a custom attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I get the value of a custom attribute using JavaScript?

Like

```html
<strong id="the_id" original-title="I NEED THIS">
```

I've tried `.getAttribute()` and jQuery’s `.attr()` without success.

Comment: You should be using HTML5 `data-*` attributes. Your current markup is invalid.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Adding custom attributes makes your HTML invalid. Use [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead:

```html
<strong id="the_id" data-original-title="I NEED THIS">
```

```js
$('#the_id').data('original-title')
```

https://jsbin.com/akoyut/2/edit

Comment: This did not update for me when the `data-` attribute changed. `$('#the_id').attr('data-original-title')` gets the current value of the attribute.

Comment: HTML invalid as in not part of the spec or that it won't work? I swear I've seen custom attributes before.

Answer (score 73):

You can do it using plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("the_id").getAttribute("original-title")
```

Comment: This is the real answer

Answer (score 3):

You can get the value by using [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
$('#the_id').attr('original-title')
```

Comment: using jquery..i've tryed it but it returns null