# how to get value of type="color" input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I used this above html code for my project..but i don't know how to get value of above input using javascript

```
<form>
  <input type="color" id="favcolor">
</form>
```

can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [`value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html#input.color.attrs.value)?

Comment: i want to get dynamic value ...

Comment: how do you usually get the value of an input tag?

Comment: @user3624843 Access the `value` attribute (of the DOM object). [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/9CCF7/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226311/get-value-of-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: create input value. but this time i want to get dynamic value of this input

Comment: The `value` attribute holds the value of the input. Whenever the user changes the value of the input, the `value` attribute changes. There's no difference between "value" and "dynamic value." If you want to get the current value, look at the `value` attribute. If you want something to happen every time the value changes, bind a [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) like you would for any other input.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To simply get the value

```js
document.getElementById("favcolor").value;
```

You can add an event listener if you want to get the color when the selection changes. You’d do something like this:

```js
var theInput = document.getElementById("favcolor");

theInput.addEventListener("input", function(){
  var theColor = theInput.value;
  
  // Do something with `theColor` here.
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="favcolor" type="color"/>
```

Here’s a working [JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/3fehj/).

Answer (score 0):

We can simply assign the color value to the label.

Sample code is here

```
<label id ="colorVal">Select color</label>
<input type="color" id ='color'>Value</input>
```

JS Code

```
let colorInput = document.getElementById('color');


colorInput.addEventListener('input', () =>{
document.getElementById('colorVal').innerHTML = colorInput.value;
});
```

Sample codepen link

https://codepen.io/ragi_jay/pen/poRMwMX

Comment: this is very similar to the answer that was accepted 7 years ago