# How would I get the value of a class like this?

Tags: jquery

`span class="robux " original-title="525 R$"> 525`

How would I get the value in the quotes by original-title?
I really need this for something.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226311/get-value-of-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript-or-jquery):

Use `data()` as it states:

```
<span class="robux " data-original-title="525 R$">525</span>

var originalTitle = $(".robux").data("original-title");
```

You can also use `attr()`

Just be sure to use both within `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 0):

By using the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$('.robux').attr('original-title');
```

You'll have to be more specific in the selector if there are multiple elements with the class `robux`.

Comment: That didn't work, sadly.

Comment: Why you said it did not work? Do you have any errors on console?

Comment: No errors, it just says "undefined", it's on this page, http://www.roblox.com/LOL-Moon-item?id=162372650