# How to get the content of the "data-files" property of an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to get the quoted content of an HTML tag.

Here's the HTML I've got :

```
<div class="html5videoplayer" id="player1" data-files="aGV5IG1hbg=="></div>
```

I'm trying to get the content of the `data-files` attribute.

The main problem is that I have no clue how you could get the contents of a specific attribute. I know I can identify the entire class or id by using `getElementById()` or `getElementsByClassName()` but to get a specific attribute is unknown for me.

If you have a clue for me I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: That is not a “tag”, but an _attribute_.

Comment: why would someone upvote this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of a Custom Attribute using Javascript or Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226311/get-value-of-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery :

```
var dataFiles = $('#player1').attr("data-files");
```

---

Without jQuery :

```
var dataFiles = document.getElementById("player1").getAttribute("data-files");
```

---

Both options should **work in any browser**!

You can try both of them at [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/awv7c8k9/).

Answer (score 4):

Use **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** function in jQuery.

```
$('#player1').data('files');
```

In simple JS,

```
var data = document.getElementById('player1').dataset.files;
```

But for older browsers like IE8 you cannot get it using dataset,

So you can use this workaroud (*only need this if you are not using jQuery, then simply use the first suggestion.*),

```
var data = document.getElementById('player1').getAttribute('data-files');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
var files = document.querySelector('#player1').dataset.files;
```

`data-*` is attribute from html5, which can be used to store specific/particular data for element. If you have multiple `data-*` attributes on your element then it will return an object with all the keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can access the content of data-files with the jquery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function

```
$("[data-files]").attr("data-files")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery `data()` function OR `attr()` function to get content

```
<div class="html5videoplayer" id="player1" data-files="aGV5IG1hbg=="></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var result_dataFun = $("#player1").attr("data-files");//Using data() function
    var result_attrFun = $("#player1").data("files"); //Using attr() function
    alert(result_dataFun);
    alert(result_attrFun);
});
</script>
```

Result :

```
aGV5IG1hbg==
```