# How to find value of element inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find the value of an element inside a div. Not the actual text of the element, but the value tag.

```html
<div id="div">
<p value="1">Example Text</p>
</div>
```

I mean find the '1' of the p, not the "Example Text". Is there a way to do this, preferably without libraries? Also, I need to be able to do this without knowing the ID of the p.

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('#div p').getAttribute('value')`

Comment: Note, custom attribute should be prefixed with `data-`, e.g. `data-value` (if you go for HTML5 standard), and with that being accessible using [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226311/get-value-of-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: The value attribute is not valid for the <p tag as suggested above use data-

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just realized, I need to know how to do this without knowing the id of the element in the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('#div > *')` to get all the elements inside that div, and iterate over each of them and print their text using `.innerHTML`

```js
var a=document.querySelectorAll('#div > *')
a.forEach((e)=>console.log(e.innerHTML))
```

```html
<div id="div">
<p id="p" value="1">Example Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Question stated "not the "Example Text" " though.....

Comment: Missed that part. Edited!