# How to get meta attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `span` element like this:

```
<span meta-nextep="ep-2-2" class="player-overlay radius4 show ep-2-1" meta-serie="TEST" meta-stag="2" meta-ep="1" meta-embed="TESTLINK" meta-embed2="TEST2" meta-embed3="TEST3"></span>
```

And I want to get the attribute of `meta-embed`, which is "TESTLINK".
I've tried `document.getElementById()`, but it doesn't work, do you know how i can do it?

Comment: `.getAttribute()`.

Comment: It really should be `data-` and not `meta-` so you can use dataset and be valid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of a Custom Attribute using Javascript or Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226311/get-value-of-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **id** for this `span` element so you can use `querySelectorAll` with a `class name` and use  `.getAttribute` to get the attribute you want from.

```js
const res = [...document.querySelectorAll(".player-overlay")].map(el =>

  el.getAttribute("meta-embed")
)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<span meta-nextep="ep-2-2" class="player-overlay radius4 show ep-2-1" meta-serie="TEST" meta-stag="2" meta-ep="1" meta-embed="TESTLINK1" meta-embed2="TEST2" meta-embed3="TEST3"></span>

<span meta-nextep="ep-2-2" class="player-overlay radius4 show ep-2-2" meta-serie="TEST" meta-stag="2" meta-ep="1" meta-embed="TESTLINK2" meta-embed2="TEST2" meta-embed3="TEST3"></span>

<span meta-nextep="ep-2-2" class="player-overlay radius4 show ep-2-3" meta-serie="TEST" meta-stag="2" meta-ep="1" meta-embed="TESTLINK3" meta-embed2="TEST2" meta-embed3="TEST3"></span>
```

Comment: And what if  i have class="player-overlay radius4 show ep-2-2 and class="player-overlay radius4 show ep-2-3" etc and i want get the meta attribute of everyone ?

Comment: i updated my code for an example of group of span update your question please